# How to check if a partialview is already rendered from another view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, gridview

im trying to implement a master/detail grid relationship, but in the detail grid i would like to show two grids.

I each time i make a sorting or a paging in one of these two details grid i execute a callback actionresult wich returns an PartialView containing the GridView that i want to update the data.

So, my view in this moment have a master grid and two details grids rendered. And the callback action is:

```
public ActionResult _FirstDetailDetailCallback()
{
        return PartialView("_FirstDetailDetail", Session["PosicaoEstoqueDetailTotvs"] as List<PosicaoEstoque>);
}
```

But the then i get an alert error with all the html that this partialview returned.

I can see all the grids with respective data but i cannot execute a callback action, is there something i missed here?

EDIT:

My master grid view call the template like this:

```
settings.SetDetailRowTemplateContent(c =>
    {
        Html.RenderAction("_FirstDetailDetail", new { //param });
        Html.RenderAction("_SecondDetailDetail", new {//param });
    });
```

Comment: have you considered using knockout and a service to get the data. you will get some performance as you will only be passing the json back and fourth. should omit the issue alltogether

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand the issue, but in your controller you can use  this.ControllerContext.IsChildAction to determine if you are inside of @Html.Action() call, which can help determine if you should be returning a partial or a full view.  Sounds like you might be calling @Html.Action() inside of your master grid page (for your two grids), and then trying to return that partial view in a full request.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your response, ive make an edit in the op showing how am i calling the template